# Undefined Output

Tags: vhdl, exponent

Every time I simulate the code below my output is undefined and I don't know why. I have the numeric library in both the code and simulation. If anyone can help let me know. Also the inputs in the simulation become 00000..000 instead of the input of 15 and 3.

MODULE CODE:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity EXPONENT_FUNCTION is
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 downto 0);
       B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 downto 0);
       O : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (47 downto 0));
end EXPONENT_FUNCTION;

architecture Behavioral of EXPONENT_FUNCTION is


signal AIN, BIN, F : integer;
signal u : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);

begin

AIN <= to_integer(signed (A));

BIN <= to_integer(signed (B));

F <= ((AIN)**(BIN));
u <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(F, 48));
O <= u;


end Behavioral;
```

SIMULATION CODE:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY EXPONENT_TEST IS
END EXPONENT_TEST;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF EXPONENT_TEST IS 



    COMPONENT EXPONENT_FUNCTION
    PORT(
         A : IN  std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
         B : IN  std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
         O : OUT  std_logic_vector(47 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;



   signal A : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal B : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := (others => '0');


   signal O : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0);

   BEGIN

   uut: EXPONENT_FUNCTION PORT MAP (
          A => A,
          B => B,
          O => O
        );


   stim_proc: process
   begin        
   A <= "000000000000000000001111";
    B <= "000000000000000000000011";
      wait for 100 ns;  


       wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Comment: If you simulate the above code on its own, its output will be undefined, because nothing is driving the inputs. You need to include the code for your testbench in your question. (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: i've updated it with the simulation code

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have undefined outputs is that you have a runtime error. This is because the exponent operator cannot be used with negative integers. If you change the types to `natural` and `unsigned`, it compiles and runs:

```
architecture Behavioral of EXPONENT_FUNCTION is

  signal AIN, BIN, F : natural;
  signal u : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);

begin

  AIN <= to_integer(unsigned (A));
  BIN <= to_integer(unsigned (B));

  F <= ((AIN)**(BIN));
  u <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(F, 48));
  O <= u;

end Behavioral;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6F3H

Comment: Thanks, but What I did was set the integer values to an initial stat of '0' and that also seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Actually all you have to do is declare BIN as a natural to stop the run time error (or as the OP indicates provide a safe initial value).